# How to create a chat application using Janus web socket in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, websocket, janus, janus-gateway

i want to use janus in react native for chat functionality. did not find any documentation. how to integrate websocket janus in react native.

i am using following react-native-janus but this is only for video room

i want to create text room in janus.

Janus.init()

how to initialize janus?

Answer (score 1):

Janus exposes its API, so feel free to use it.

You may use Janus Javascript API for your purposes:
https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/JS.html

Read about using janus.js library here:
https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/js-modules.html

Then look at the TextRoom docs:
https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/textroom.html

Comment: Thnx it works. but i am getting an error Like this . Error: Is the gatway down? Janus.ajax request fails.

Comment: Make sure that Janus is running.
If you're running Janus behind web server, check if reverse proxy is enabled and configured: https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/deploy.html